# Google Play Game Services iOS review issue

Tags: ios, google-play-games

I've created multiplatform game that uses Google Play Game Services.

But Apple rejected it with reason:
Providing other general platform references, is not appropriate in the context of the App Store. In addition, it would be appropriate to remove 'Google Play' access to be in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Did anybody have success with submitting app that supports Google Play Game Services?

Comment: "Providing other general platform references, is not appropriate in the context of the App Store" Isn't this just a text / documentation issue - they don't like the references to Google Play in your promotional material ?

Comment: "It would be appropriate to" does not mean "you must" ?

Comment: I don't have references to Google Play in promotional materials for iOS app. Also my app was accepted as soon as I disabled gpgs.